# Check Technical feature automatically for admin

Tags: odoo-8, role

I need to assign **Technical feature** group to admin during installing my custom module. I tried below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <openerp>
   <data>
     <record model="res.users" id="base.user_root">
      <field name="partner_id" ref="base.partner_root"/>
      <field name="company_id" ref="base.main_company"/>
      <field name="company_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.main_company'))]"/>
      <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_no_one'))]"/>  <!--ams.group_residents -->
      <field name="signature"><![CDATA[<span>--<br/>
            Administrator</span>]]></field>
    </record>
  </data>
 </openerp>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `base.group_no_one` to `groups_id` is sufficient:

```
<record model="res.users" id="base.user_root">
  <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_no_one'))]"/>
</record>
```